# My VS Code auto-complete display question mark instead of character

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code display question mark when I use autocomplete function, every character not utf8 or other encoding?
Can anyone please help?, Thank you.

##### Update

My about info

```
Version: 1.83.1
Commit: f1b07bd25dfad64b0167beb15359ae573aecd2cc
Date: 2023-10-10T23:57:32.750Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.0.0
```

I am also disable all extensions but it still display question mark symbol, may be some OS settings affected this problem ?
[image: autocomplete question mark]

Comment: 3) Please provide an exact, minimal procedure to reproduce this issue. Include every single piece of info necessary to reproduce the necessary environment.

Comment: still waiting for the [mre]. Also you should say what language it is you're writing in.